# I have known him vs I know him

Tags: verbs, idiomatic-language

1. I know him for a long time.
2. I have known him for a long time.

There doesn't seem to be any doubt that 2 is perfectly correct and perfectly idiomatic; however, I'm not so sure about 1.

**My questions:**

1. Is 1 a correct sentence?
2. Does 1 express the same meaning as 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, #1 is not a correct sentence.
And, as a result, no, #1 does not express the same meaning as #2.

For what it's worth, related correct sentences (none of which mean the same as your #2) include:

> I knew him for a long time.
>
> I had known him for a long time.
>
> I will have known him for a long time.
>
> I would have known him for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

**I know him from school.
I know him from work.**

**I know him well.**

**I don't know him at all.**

**The simple present in English is for *general statements*. It can't be said enough.** It is not used with expressions of time using *for and since.*

The present perfect is for adding expressions of time, for example:
I've known him for ages, for two weeks, for only 24-hours.

Obviously, other tenses can also be used but the question here was not about them. Please note: the verb **know** is stative and not usually used in a continuous tense.

Comment: Just to be clear, is sentence 1 a grammatical sentence as well?

Comment: No, not at all. If it had been I would have said so. I just explained why it isn't.